# SAP Solution Manager Connect to Microsoft Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, integration, sap-solution-manager

Do any of you know if its possible to make a document sharing between SAP and Microsoft Sharepoint?

What I would like is to use SAP - Solution Manager as document storeage and connect this storage to Sharepoint. Updating and using the documents on Sharepoint but having the documents located in Solution Manager.

I know that its possible to have the document located on Sharepoint and link to Solution Manager but cant find any information about the other way around.
I would like to avoid Duet Enterprice Software and other programmes like this - Since we are having a low budget.